# POST to VoilaNorbert API from Rails with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I am trying to POST data to the standard [VoilaNorbert search API endpoint](http://api.voilanorbert.com/2018-01-08/#search-endpoint) using the HTTParty Rails gem:

```
response = HTTParty.post(
  'https://api.voilanorbert.com/2018-01-08/search/name',
  query: {
    'name': 'Elon Musk', 
    'domain': 'https://www.tesla.com/'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': VOILANORBERT_API_TOKEN
  }
)
```

However, when I try this simple request, I get the response:

```
 => {"name"=>["This field is required."]}
```

My understanding is that the query block above is supposed to pass along the name field, which in this case is "Elon Musk".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I succeeded by realizing I needed to change the payload to send form-data in the body of the request rather than as query params. This requires using the `body` block to encode form fields, as well as the multipart method on the request indicating that data is being uploaded.

```
response = HTTParty.post(
  'https://api.voilanorbert.com/2018-01-08/search/name',
   body: {
     name: 'Elon',
     domain: 'https://www.tesla.com/'  
   },
   multipart: true,
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': VOILANORBERT_API_TOKEN
   }
)
```